# Help with Twitter API with TwitterOAuth and PHP with object attributes

Tags: php, object, twitter, methods

i have been doing some integration with twitter using php and this api: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

I've managed to tweet, but im having some difficulties in understand and evaluate the return values.

For instance in the file callback.php if i want to post a tweeter i have this code:

```
$result = $connection->post(  
'statuses/update',  
array(  
    'status' => 'Tweet teste de API!',  
));
```

but how do i know what $result is returning me? i've tried to echo it and for it but it doesnt seem to work, any insights on that? I want to be able to see all the returning keys available.

I've tried this:
`foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key, $value <br />";
}`

but it only prints two keys then a error appers that i cant convert stdclass. Any insight on how to see this or better api documentation?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When posting with `statuses/update`, the returned `$result` will be a PHP class/object containing the created tweet, structured the same as `status/show:id`.

It looks like http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update fails to mention that the created tweet will be returned upon success. But if you read the bottom of http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id, you can see all the different data you can access from `$result`.

You should also be able to see the object's entirety with `var_dump($result)`.

This example should hopefully work for you; it posts the tweet, then echos the created tweet's text and the user's screen name:

```
$result = $connection->post(
    'statuses/update',
    array('status' => 'Tweet teste de API!') // no comma needed here, by the way
);
if ($result->id) {
    // Tweet posted successfully, and $result contains the tweet data
    echo $result->text . '<br />Tweeted by @' . $result->user->screen_name;
} else {
    // Tweet failed
    echo 'Status failed to be updated.';
}
```

Similarly, pretty much any Twitter resource found on http://dev.twitter.com/doc can be accessed with `$result = $connection->post()`.

Just have the 1st parameter be a string of the desired resource (eg `statuses/update` or `users/show`), and the 2nd parameter be an array of the resource's parameters, then you can access whatever the resource returns with `$result`.

The Twitter API is at your fingertips, and abraham's twitteroauth library makes it easy :)

Comment: Thank you it really helped me. Do you for instance, i have a server that always be posting automated twitts, do i need to get the authorizations everytime? Can i use store it in some database and reuse? Like a infinite session on facebook?

Comment: When your user account authenticates with Twitter, if you save the returned user token Key and Secret in a database or other storage method, you can just use the saved Key and Secret again. This way you don't have to authenticate every time :)

Comment: Twitter resources that require method GET will be `$connection->get()`, and DELETE will be `$connection->delete()`.